# Julia Differentiation

Tags: julia, differentiation

I have been looking on many different pages for a suitable Julia package to compute a similar (but more complicated) differentiation to the one below.

Say we have a function f(x)=5x[1]^4 - 2x[2]^2
is there a way to compute the partial derivative of this function with respect to x[1] say, but I would want the result in Julia gives simply as 20x[1]^3 to be used onwards in the code as the result would be if x[1] and x[2] were to be say x and y specifically?

I have looked into ForwardDiff as this deals with vector notation thus far but only encountered errors when implementing it.
I am using the vector notation as x[1] and x[2] and the vector representations used later on in the code for the hcubature package for double integrations.

Comment: What did you want the "correct" result for `f(x)=5x[1]^4 - 2x[2]^2` to be?

Comment: Sorry could you clarify the question? I'm not seeing how 20x[1]^3 is an incorrect partial derivative wrt x[1]

Comment: Apologies I mistyped. I meant that I would want the code to give me a result in that form (i.e a generic form of 20x[1]^3) for me to use onwards to place into the hcubature package for an integration. I am unsure how exactly to implement this as a partial derivative against x[1] only and not all of x=(x[1],x[2])

Comment: I see. Answering below for readability.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're looking for something that can be handled by `Symbolics.jl`. This snippet does what you're looking for:

```
using Symbolics
@variables x[1:2]
D₁ = Differential(x[1])
eq = 5x[1]^4 - 2x[2]^2
expand_derivatives(D₁(eq))
```

This will return `20(x[1]^3)`. You can use this as a  symbolic expression in other equations. [This resource](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/dev/manual/variables/#:%7E:text=Symbolics%20supports%20creating%20variables%20that%20denote%20an%20array%20of%20some%20size.&text=A%20symbol%20or%20expression%20that,expressions%20using%20the%20scalarize%20function.&text=Note%20that%20%40variables%20returns%20a%20vector%20of%20all%20the%20defined%20variables.) shows how symbolic arrays are declared in Julia, and [this one](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/v1.2/manual/derivatives/#Symbolics.expand_derivatives) shows how the `Differential` operator is used.